# Is there a simple method of displaying Bounding Boxes on Firebase Image

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am using Firebase ML Kit on android studio to capture an image and then detect text.

Currently I take the picture with the phone's camera and this image is displayed in the app. I click my detect text button and the text appears. But I would like to see some bounding boxes on the images that shows what Firebase ML kit is seeing.

I have found many ways to do this in Kotlin, but I am a new developer and I feel like I need to figure out how to do this in Java before completely changing my whole code to Kotlin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ML Kit provides an API to get boundingbox for recognized text:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/text/FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock

Also, in the quickstart app, ML Kit provides an example about how to do it:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/kotlin/textrecognition/TextGraphic.kt#L32